# How to generate proto java files using gradle and wire compiler?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, protocol-buffers

I would like to run gradle task that generates for me java files from proto files. Here is my code:

```
task runJar(dependsOn: jar) << {
    javaexec {
        main = "-jar";
        args = [
                "wire-compiler-1.8.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar",
                "--proto_path=src/main/proto",
                "--java_out=build/generated/proto/wire test.proto"
        ]
    }
}
```

Everything is fine via command line, but in gradle it does not work.

```
java -jar wire-compiler-1.8.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar --proto_path=src/main/proto --java_out=build/generated/proto/wire test.proto
```

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I found the problem. It should look like this:

```
task runJar(dependsOn: jar) << {
    javaexec {
        main = "-jar";
        args = [
                "wire-compiler-1.8.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar",
                "--proto_path=src/main/proto",
                "--java_out=build/generated/proto/wire",
                "test.proto"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post the update as an answer and mark this question as answered. It's OK to answer one's own questions.